# Image and h2 won't align horizontaly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a header for a form. The header contains img (logo) and h2.

HTML:

```
<div>
     <img src="../ekspedit/rotografika-logo-80.png" alt=""/>
     <h2>PRIJAVA NEUSAGLAŠENOSTI</h2>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img{
     display:inline-block;
}
h2{
     display:inline-block;
}
```

There are a few posts with the same problem, but all answers are the same: put inline-block on img and h2 elements, but that doesn't work the way I want it to. This solution displays h2 next to the logo but with top margin. This top margin is the same height as th logo.

I want the h2 to be inline with the logo.

Can someone explain this behaviour and how to fix it?

Comment: You can fix that with the `vertical-align: middle property`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add to the image attributtes vertical-align:middle;

https://jsfiddle.net/4pahqjr6/

```
img{
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: simple answer, this is better

Answer (score 0):

Is this you are looking for

**option 1**

```css
.one {
  display: table;
}
.one img {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.one h2 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
     <img src="https://images.google.com/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" alt=""/>
     <h2>PRIJAVA NEUSAGLAŠENOSTI</h2>
</div>
```

**option 2**

```css
img{
     float:left;
}
h2{
     margin:0;
     padding-top:8%;
}
```

```html
<div>
     <img src="https://images.google.com/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" alt=""/>
     <h2>PRIJAVA NEUSAGLAŠENOSTI</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:absolute` to h2:

```
h2{
   display: inline-block;
   position: absolute;
}
```