# How do I move this logo onto my header without moving title?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website and I want to make the title and logo to be on the header with the title in the center and logo on the left.

The issue is the title is pushing the logo down.

I've tried the following:

- Margin
- Padding
- Moving the code around
- Changing "Display"

What else could I try?

```
.header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgb(204, 31, 0);
}
.titlemain {
    font-size: 4vw;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1.5%;
    margin-block-start: 0;
    margin-block-end: 0;
    margin-inline-start: 0;
    margin-inline-end: 0;
}
```

https://pastebin.com/Vvw7LtQE - CSS

```
<div class="header">
        <h1 class="titlemain">The Little Beauty Studio</h1>
        <img class="logomain" src="img/lblogo.png" alt="The PHP logo">
    </div>
```

https://pastebin.com/0BKmtkZ8 - HTML

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is because `h1` tag is block level, so it's taking the whole width of div

Comment: You can tell the `<h1>` to display inline or you could float the logo left or right and that will also help you achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks guys, I fixed it by displaying inline, then floating the logo left and adjusting the padding to center the text and position the logo

Comment: or try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45506657/image-and-h2-wont-align-horizontaly?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

try this code:
css:

```
.header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgb(204, 31, 0);
}
.titlemain {
    font-size: 4vw;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1.5%;
    margin-block-start: 0;
    margin-block-end: 0;
    margin-inline-start: 0;
    margin-inline-end: 0;
}
.header img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 41%;
    left: 3%;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="header">
    <h1 class="titlemain">The Little Beauty Studio</h1>
    <img class="logomain" src="img/lblogo.png" alt="The PHP logo">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your HTML structure, I would do it this way:

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
  <img class="logomain" src="img/lblogo.png" alt="The PHP logo">
  <h1 class="titlemain">The Little Beauty Studio</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgb(204, 31, 0);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.header img,
.header h1 {
  align-self: center;
}

h1 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by displaying inline, then floating the logo left and adjusting the padding to center the text and position the logo.

```
.logomain {
  float: left;
  padding: 2.5px 13.5% 0 175px;
}
.titlemain {
    font-size: 4vw;
    padding-top: 1.5%;
    margin-block-start: 0;
    margin-block-end: 0;
    margin-inline-start: 0;
    margin-inline-end: 0;
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a website, I'd very much like to recommend you use a UI framework (Bootstrap) which will make most of the tasks easier for you.

They are providing a pre-defined set of styles using which you can overcome many primitive issues and also, you can do a really good job with your projects. Most of the commercially available HTML websites use Bootstrap or something related.

That being said, let's look into your problem. This is the simplest way to get done what you want.

```
<div class="header">
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img class="logomain" src="img/lblogo.png" alt="The PHP logo">
            </td>
            <td>
                <h1 class="titlemain">The Little Beauty Studio</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Now let's see how we can improve this with the use of Bootstrap!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <!-- Brand/logo -->
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    
    <!-- Links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Do some lite Google search on the topic and you can find some good materials with reference to this.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

**HTML**

```
<header>
  <img  src="https://api.akeneo.com/img/illustrations/illus--Assetcategory.svg">
  <h1>Your Title Area</h1>
</header>
```

**Css**

```
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border:solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 4em;
}
header img {
   width:100px;
   float:left;
}
header h1{
  text-align:center;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ajimon/msc3opq5/25/